# Cakephp date automagic

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have the follow code:

```
echo $this->Form->input('date', array(
        'label' => __('Date')
    )
);
```

which generate one `select` for year, one for month and one for day. I want one input text instead of `select` which I can put all date. So, I have done:

```
echo $this->Form->input('date', array(
        'label' => __('Date'),
        'type' => 'text'
    )
);
```

Form works but validation does not works, I can't get the correct data (Cake's "automagic") at Controller, but can't find what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to validate that the value is a date, use this in the model:

```
public $validate = array(
   'your_date_column' => array(
           'rule'       => 'date',
           'message'    => 'Enter a valid date'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the form helper like this:

```
$this->Form->date('demo', array('type' => 'date'));
```

The resulting date data will be received in the controller in this format:

```
$this->request->data['Model_name']['demo']['month'];
$this->request->data['Model_name']['demo']['day'];
$this->request->data['Model_name']['demo']['year'];
```

In your case if you use a textbox like this:

```
$this->Form->date('demo', array('type' => 'string'));
```

You will get your date like this:

```
$this->request->data['Model_name']['demo'];
```

I dont know how you want to get the date or how you store it on your database, but you have to take this into consideration when you change from one type to another.